# Simulating a 6-faced die in Ada-2005

Tags: ada

I have very definitively come across the 'simulating a 6-faced die' (which produces a random integer between 1 and 6, all outcomes are equally probable) in Java, Python, Ruby and Bash. However, I am yet to see a similar program in Ada. Has anyone come across one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Random Number Generation (LRM [A.5.2](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-5-2.html)) for packages to assist with doing this. Either Ada.Numerics.Float_Random for uniform random number generation (range 0.0 .. 1.0) which you can then scale on your own, or instantiate Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random with a suitable (sub)type (works for d4, d10, d12, and d20s as well!).

Answer (score 3):

You might enjoy this simulation of the children's [card game of war](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/war), which uses an instance of [`Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random`](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-5-2.html).

```ada
subtype Card_Range is Positive range 1 .. 52;
package Any_Card is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Card_Range);
G : Any_Card.Generator;
…
N : Card_Range := Any_Card.Random(G);
```

Answer (score 2):

With Ada 95, a random number generator was defined as part of the standard library making it a required component of every Ada 95 compilation system.

Therefore, yes you can simulate a 6-faced die in Ada quite easily.

Comment: That's probably why he hasn't come across such a thing. It would be too trivial to bother with.

Comment: Could be, T.E.D ..... however, most surprisingly, I have not even come across any sort of stochastic structure being programmed in Ada.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you, dude. One of the first things I ever coded in Ada back in 1989 was a random number generator. Sadly, I took the algorithm from a textbook and didn't really investigate the effect that the interface I provided for it had on the algorithim. It turned out that if you asked for a random value with a suitably small range (I think it was 0-3), it alternated between two results. This is why it is best to leave such things to the experts. :-)

Comment: Phew ! ..... seems Ada did some parallel processing in randomisation too .... T.E.D, if you do find that program then please do send it across ! ... :)

Answer (score 0):

RossetaCode.org usually have these kind of typical programs. You can find a simple 6-faced dice implementation in [Pig the dice game](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pig_the_dice_game#Ada).

These are the relevant parts of that program for a dice implementation.

You define the wanted range in a type:

```
type Dice_Score is range 1 .. 6;
```

instantiate Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random with your type:

```
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;

package RND is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Dice_Score);
```

Use the instantiation to get a random value in the range:

```
Gen: RND.Generator; 

P.Recent_Roll := RND.Random(Gen);
```